# Validate same form elements with different rules for save and submit using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, save, submit

Im trying to validate form fields using JQuery validation plugin. Im using jquery 1.10.2. there are lot of posts on this but none helped me with the solution that im trying to implement. Hence posting this question. I want to validate the form on save and submit. I have defined set of rules on each element on submit. It is working fine. Now, on click of save button, i just need to remove "required: true" from the validation rules. Rest of the validation rules defined are same for save and submit.

When I try the above change, I always get "Object doesn't support property or method 'rules'". Im using IE 9 (we are using IE in our project. Need to get this working in IE).

Below is the  code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myForm").formValidate();
});

jQuery.fn.formValidate = function(){

var form = this;

// Set the error to null
$("#errSummary").val('');

$(form).validate({

    //Not to place the error messages in line with the text fields
    errorPlacement: $.noop,

    //Create error summary that will appear before the form
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    if (errorList) {

        var $errorFormId = 'errors-' + form.attr('id');

        //Reset and remove error messages if the form has been validated once already
        //summary = "";

        // Set the summary to original error messages stored as part of submit
        // This helps to retain the error messages until there is a new submit
        summary = $("#errSummary").val();

        //$('label .error', form).remove();

        //Create container for error msg display
        if($('#' + $errorFormId).length == 0) {
            $('<div id="' + $errorFormId + '"/>').insertAfter("#header");
        }

        //Generate error summary list
        if (summary.length == 0){

            for (error in errorList) {
                //get associated label text to be used for the error summary
                var $errorLabel = $('label[for="' + $(errorList[error].element).attr('id') + '"]').text();
                summary += '<li><a href="#' + errorList[error].element.id + '" name="' + errorList[error].element.name + '" class="errorLink">' + $errorLabel + ' ' + errorList[error].message + '</a></li>';
            }

            //Output error summary and place it in the error container
            if(summary) {
                $('#' + $errorFormId).html('<h2>Errors found in the form</h2><p>One or more errors found in form. Please check and correct the following:</p><ul>' + summary + '</ul>').css("margin-left", "5px");
            } else {
                $('#' + $errorFormId).html('');
            }

            // Set the errSummary to current error messages for the most recent submit              
            $("#errSummary").val(summary);
         }

        //Move the focus to the associated input when error message link is triggered
        $('#' + $errorFormId + ' a').click(function() {

      $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
            return false;
        });
    }
    this.defaultShowErrors();
    submitted = false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
        submitted = true;
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false
});

var saveRules = {
field1: {
required: false,
digits: true,
minlength: 7,
maxlength: 10
}   
};

var submitRules = {
field1: {
required: true,
digits: true,
minlength: 7,
maxlength: 10
}   
};

function addRules(rulesObj){
for (var item in rulesObj){
       $('#'+item).rules('add',rulesObj[item]);  
} 
}

function removeRules(rulesObj){
for (var item in rulesObj){
       $('#'+item).rules('remove');  
} 
}

$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {

if ($(this).attr('id') == "saveForm") {
    removeRules(submitRules);
    addRules(saveRules);
} else {        
    removeRules(saveRules);
    addRules(submitRules);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this error occur in all browsers or just IE?

Comment: This error occurs in IE only